# How to get a value from a two-dimensional list that is in an adjacent column from one that matches the value of another two-dimensional list

Tags: python, for-loop

I have 2 files I converted to list of lists format. Short examples

```
a

c1 165.001 17593685 

c2 1650.94 17799529

c3 16504399 17823261

b

1 rs3094315 **0.48877594** *17593685* G A

1 rs12562034 0.49571378 768448 A G

1 rs12124819 0.49944228 776546 G A
```

Using the cycle 'for'  I tried to find the common values of these lists, but I can't loop the process. It is necessary since I need to get an value that is adjacent to the value that is common to the two lists(in this given example it is **0.48877594** since 17593685 is common for 'a' and 'b'  . My attempts that completely froze:

```
for i in a:

        if i[2] == [d[3] for d in b]:

                print(i[0], i[2] + d[2])
```

or

```
for i in a and d in b:

        if i[2] == d[3]

                print(i[0], i[2] + d[2]
```

Overall I need to get the first file with a new column, which will be that bold adjacent value. Is is my first month of programming and I cant understand logic. Thanks in advance!

+++

List's original format:

a = [['c1', '165.001', '17593685'], ['c2', '1650.94', '17799529'], ['c3', '16504399', '17823261']]
[['c1', '16504399', '17593685.1\n'], ['c2', '16504399', '17799529.1\n'], ['c3', '16504399', '17823261.\n']]

++++ My original data

Two or more people can have DNA segments that are the same, because they were inherited from a common ancestor. File 'a' contains the following columns:
SegmentID, Start of segment, End of Segment, IDs of individuals that share this segment(from 2 to infinity). Example(just a little part since real list has > 1000 raws - segments('c'). Number of individuals can be different.
c1 16504399 17593685 19N 19N.0 19N 19N.0 182AR 182AR.0 182AR 182AR.0 6i 6i.1 6i 6i.1 153A 153A.1 153A 153A.1

c2 14404399 17799529 62BB 62BB.0 62BB 62BB.0 55k 55k.0 55k 55k.0 190k 190k.0 190k 190k.0 51A 51A.1 51A 51A.1 3A 3A.1 3A 3A.1 38k 38k.1 38k 38k.1

c3 1289564 177953453 164Bur 164Bur.0 164Bur 164Bur.0 38BO 38BO.1 38BO 38BO.1 36i 36i.1 36i 36i.1 100k 100k.1 100k 100k.1

file b:

This one always has 6 columns but number of rows more the 100 millions, so only it's part:

1 rs3094315 0.48877594 16504399 G A

1 rs12562034 0.49571378 17593685 A G

1 rs12124819 0.49944228 14404399 G A

1 rs3094221 0.48877594 17799529 G A

1 rs12562222 0.49571378 1289564 A G

1 rs121242223 0.49944228 177953453 G A

So, I need to compare  a[1] with b[3] and if they are equal 
print(a[1],b[3]), because b[3] is position of segment too but in another measurement system. That is what I can't do

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the data in list format because at the moment looking at those numbers it's difficult to know what you're asking.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your question

Comment: You can edit your question and put it in there.

Comment: Rob Kwasowski, why did you delete your answer? Was it wrong? I fell asleep yesterday night and did not try it

Comment: user3483203, I seem to have added all of this list. I will try to edit my post later, after work.

Comment: You code attempts to compare `a[2] == b[3]` but you description says `a[1] == b[3]` and you are print `a[2], b[2]` not `a[1], b[3]` - so confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a leap (because the question isn't really clear), I think you are looking for the `product` of `a`, `b`, e.g.:

```
In []:
for i in a:
    for d in b:
        if i[2] == d[3]:
            print(i[0], i[2] + d[2])

Out[]:
c1 175936850.48877594
```

You can do the same with `itertools.product()`:

```
In []:
import itertools as it

for i, d in it.product(a, b):
    if i[2] == d[3]:
        print(i[0], i[2] + d[2])

Out[]:
c1 175936850.48877594
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked but only on that simulated short data. On real example it has given me error:"File "Genetics", line 17, in <module>
    if i[2] == d[3]: .Error: list index out of range. Also even on simulated data, your first advice(script without itertools) gives the same error
Index

Comment: My real data looks the same but they have much more raws

Comment: You will need to post your real data. In your example above `b` has `>4` elements and `a` has `3` elements this would not throw an exception if that is the case.

Comment: I add additional information in the end of the post. I really got stuck and would be very grateful for the help

Comment: I did it! Thank you! Your answer was right. I just confused in converting of my files into the 2d format and that was the reason for error

Comment: Great, please see what to do when [Someone Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

It would be much faster to leave your data as strings and search:

```
for a_line in [_ for _ in a.split('\n') if _]: # skip blank lines
    search_term = a_line.strip().split()[-1] # get search term
    term_loc_in_b = b.find(search_term) #get search term loction in file b
    if term_loc_in_b !=-1: #-1 means term not found
        # split b once just before search term starts
        value_in_b = b[:term_loc_in_b].strip().rsplit(maxsplit=1)[-1] 
        print(value_in_b)
    else:
        print('{} not found'.format(search_term))
```

If the file size is large you might consider using [mmap](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/mmap.html) to search b.

*mmap.find requires bytes, eg. 'search_term'.encode()*